# How do I access the route information (HTTP verb, action name, etc . . .) from within a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reflection, routes, controller

Say I'm within a controller and I want to get a list of the actions and HTTP verbs that it supports, how would I do that?. E.g.

```
controller.actions # { [ :show, :get ], [ :update, :put ], . . .  }
```

Or something equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
controller = "users"
controller_routes = []
Rails.application.routes.routes.each do |route|
  if route.to_s.include?(":controller=>\"#{controller}\"")  
    controller_routes << route
  end  
end
puts controller_routes
```

You get the idea.

Comment: That doesn't include the HTTP verb, and it seems wicked messy, do you know of a way to look them up by controller?

Comment: What you mean HTTP Verb? If it's it the HTTP action(GET, PUT) you do get them: ["POST", "/users(.:format)", "{:action=>\"create\",", ":controller=>\"users\"}"] see this is POST create in users. The problem is that routes are not handled by controllers. They are handled by the ActionDispatcher, and not exposed by controller.

Comment: HTTP Verb is GET, POST, et . . . Routing handles the verb and the path to the controller. What I need to do is find a way to get the actions and associated verbs. I can get the actions by grabbing all public instance methods for a controller but there seems like there should be a relatively clean way to get the verb associated with the action.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason why I am doing this is so that I can automatically reflect on the controller to publish available RESTful methods for a service API.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see, you do get the verb. Cool, I suppose this will work though it's messy as hell. I didn't see that at first because our routeset had some non HTTP Verb constrained routes and those were the ones I was seeing pop up.